# how to solve trigonometric equations on python

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation-solving

I am trying to solve 3 of trigonometric equations in python. I used Sympy library but I got a error such as 'TypeError: can't convert expression to float'

Here is My Python Source code:

```
from sympy import Symbol, solve, Eq
from math import*

# Robot Arm length
L1 = 0
L2 = 97.9
L3 = 120
L4 = 120
L5 = 184

# location
x = L1+L2+L3+L4+L5
y = 0
z = 0

x1 = Symbol('x1',real = True)
x2 = Symbol('x2',real = True)
x3 = Symbol('x3',real = True)

#trigonometric equations

e1= Eq(L1 - (5*sin(x1))/2 - L4*(cos(x1)*sin(x2)*sin(x3) - cos(x1)*cos(x2)*cos(x3)) - L5*(cos(x4)*(cos(x1)*sin(x2)*sin(x3) - cos(x1)*cos(x2)*cos(x3)) + sin(x4)*(cos(x1)*cos(x2)*sin(x3) + cos(x1)*cos(x3)*sin(x2))) + L2*cos(x1) + L3*cos(x1)*cos(x2) - x)
e2= Eq((5*cos(x1))/2 + L4*(cos(x2)*cos(x3)*sin(x1) - sin(x1)*sin(x2)*sin(x3)) + L5*(cos(x4)*(cos(x2)*cos(x3)*sin(x1) - sin(x1)*sin(x2)*sin(x3)) - sin(x4)*(cos(x2)*sin(x1)*sin(x3) + cos(x3)*sin(x1)*sin(x2))) + L2*sin(x1) + L3*cos(x2)*sin(x1) - y)
e3= Eq(-L4*(cos(x2)*sin(x3) + cos(x3)*sin(x2)) - L3*sin(x2) - L5*(cos(x4)*(cos(x2)*sin(x3) + cos(x3)*sin(x2)) + sin(x4)*(cos(x2)*cos(x3) - sin(x2)*sin(x3))) - z)

solve([e,e2,e3],x1,x2,x3)

x1 = degrees(x1)
x2 = degrees(x2)
x3 = degrees(x3)

print("degree values : ",x1,x2,x3)
```

I added My error message:

[image]

Can anyone tell me which part should I change in my code?

Comment: I don't see the line that is causing the error in the script.

Answer (score 7):

`from math import *` is the major error here. The functions `math.sin` and `math.cos` are for numeric computation only, you can't give them symbolic arguments. Any mathematical functions must be imported from SymPy in order to use them in symbolic computations.

Guideline: when using SymPy, don't import anything from `math`. Changing the import to

```
from sympy import *
```

will solve most of the issue. You'll still have to define `x4` that's currently undefined.

Comment: Yes. It works this way. I checked. I knew that using `from math import *` could be bad decision here. Upvoted!
@Suyoung Check this. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't show me any error anymore but It seems to take so long time to compute equations....

Comment: @Suyoung It's a complicated system of nonlinear equations. At a glance, I would guess there is no analytic solution for it. That's a mathematical issue, not a SymPy issue. You may be able to find a numeric solution by using SciPy instead.v

Answer (score 1):

In this line from the source code in the original question, I believe the typo **e** should be re-written **e1**

> solve([**e**,e2,e3],x1,x2,x3)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you without seeing the full code but it looks like your variable "x4" on line e3 has not been declared anywhere.